# Warning TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca ted

Tags: mysql

I don't know the reason,tonight is the first time that I met this question.I want to start mysql,but failed.The image shows the error message.Who can help me?

[image: [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).]

[image]

Comment: That is just a warning. Are you sure it failed because of that?

Comment: I add another image..

Comment: It looks like the reason for not starting may be an error in a startup script - the TIMESTAMP message is just a warning. As you haven't specified one on your commandline - check for init-file being defined in the MySQL config file. Maybe just creating the missing elp subfolder will solve the problem.